# Wordpress 3.8 - Dashboard 1 Column Screen Options

Tags: widgets, dashboard, screen-options, screen-layout

With the new Wordpress 3.8 under Screen Options they seem to have misplaced the "Columns" feature where you could put your widgets into 1 Column, 2 Columns, 3 Columns, or 4 Columns. My question is how to I force my Dashboard Widgets to only be 1 column, or in other words, take up the whole width of the screen versus just a portion of the screen?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Another solution is to add the columns setting back to the settings.

```
function wpse126301_dashboard_columns() {
    add_screen_option(
        'layout_columns',
        array(
            'max'     => 2,
            'default' => 1
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_head-index.php', 'wpse126301_dashboard_columns' );
```

[image: Screenshot of the Screen Layout setting]

There is a related Trac ticket: [#26354](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26354)

Comment: where should that code be entered?

Comment: @jgauffin You could put that in your currently active theme's `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 8):

This happens because of the new media queries. A very unfortunate change …

Anyway, you can change it by setting a custom width for `.postbox-container`.

Use 50% for two columns and 100 % for just one column.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-index.php', function()
{
    ?>
<style>
.postbox-container {
    min-width: 100% !important;
}
.meta-box-sortables.ui-sortable.empty-container { 
    display: none;
}
</style>
    <?php
});
```

Comment: You may also want to add in this to hide the empty box: 

`.meta-box-sortables.ui-sortable.empty-container {
display: none;
}`

Comment: this might be nice for all page, but what about a single widget ?