# Make Post Editor Select Number of Columns To 1 By Default

Tags: posts, editor, screen-options

I want to make the Number of Columns in screen options for a custom post type is selected to 1 by default, instead of 2, which means full screen. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is how I did it. This hook into the admin head, find the screen options part and set the default checked radio button to `1`, which mean full screen.

Just found the answer from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126301/wordpress-3-8-dashboard-1-column-screen-options) and give it a little modification:

```
        add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse1152474_post_editor_columns');

        function wpse1152474_post_editor_columns() {
        global $pagenow, $typenow;
        if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' || $pagenow == 'post.php' 
           || $pagenow == 'post-new.php'
           && $typenow=='your_targeted_post_type') {
            add_screen_option(
                'layout_columns',
                array(
                    'max'     => 2,
                    'default' => 1
                )
            );
          }
        }
```